.Net Remoting to WCF Data Serialization/Deserialization
I have a legacy application which is using .Net Remoting and I have to migrate it to WCF. So far I have successfully migrated the endpoints, service self hosting calling from client and it went good till here. Now when I am making the data also compatible it is getting me headache. Standard modifications like making classses from [Serializable] to [DataContract] and members as[DataMember] then I am getting introduced to BinaryFormatter, SerializationBinder and what not and getting to know all these are not compatible with WCF and I have to change those as well may be using DataContractResolver but then its methods also I have to implement which will be different than SerializationBinder. Going forward what else I will get while digging up the code I am getting scared. Any help would be appreciated or how much this change is feasible to do within a month?

At the moment, based on your questions and some related descriptions, I can only give a few suggestions:
1.There is a migration note in MSDN that can help you. It is a comprehensive document of the key points of transition between the two frameworks.
Migrating from .NET Remoting to WCF
2.Based on the modifications above the configuration file, you can use the Microsoft WCF Service Configuration Editor. It can quickly help you convert configuration files between two frameworks.
3.You can check how to use script automation to complete the conversion (I think this step is quite effective, but it covers more knowledge points).
